# Anaconda3 and defaualt python conflict in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed anaconda and my python script is showing this error even I installed numpy;

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "rbm_chords.py", line 3, in 
>       import numpy as np
>     File "/home/sonu/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/**init**.py", line 146, in 
>       from . import add_newdocs
>     File "/home/sonu/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in 
>       from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
>     File "/home/sonu/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/**init**.py", line 8, in 
>       from .type_check import *
>     File "/home/sonu/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in 
>       import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
>     File "/home/sonu/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py", line 24, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>   ImportError: 
>   Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
>   likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
>   If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
>   files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Is there any way to select all the libs of conda in a particular environment.
The only suggestion I got after searching over web is to uninstall anyone.My script is working in python 2.7 and working perfectly with the default python.

Comment: Did you by any chance use `pip` to install `numpy`?

Comment: I used **conda -f install numpy** and **conda -f install numpy** in the conda environment.

Comment: conda -f? What does the -f do? Any links? I can't find it in the help message.

Comment: ohkk . This is fault .

Comment: but do i need to install all the packages in all environments that I'll create?

Comment: Yes, if you create an environment you have to control exactly what goes into it.

Comment: How exactly we control. Please give me idea to do so.

Comment: You can learn all about creating and managing environments [here](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html). Please try to do some research. People aren't here to be your personal IT support.

Comment: So, if as you say your script is working with the default Python, that means you've installed `numpy` on the defautl version. I've heard of this causing problems when you use `anaconda`.

Comment: @Juanpa. I am not asking for any IT support. I just asked the way . SO that you told me and thank you for the ideas and I'll try to accomplish my task with your ideas buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using python3 version of Anaconda but the default python for Ubuntu is python2.7

This may help you:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-anaconda-python-distribution-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I installed anaconda using this tutorial and created my_env with python 2.7 but I am getting error when I am executing my script in this environment.

Comment: How we can list all the libs of anaconda in my_env

Comment: @SonuChauhan with your environment activated, use `conda list`

Comment: conda list only shows libs that are in the anaconda and I made environemt as per the @Jimmy's given link and it isn't getting all the libs. I think I need install all using conda install numpy and all .

Comment: what do you mean by "conda list only shows the libs that are in the anaconda"??? That doesn't make sense. If you installed packages through `pip` in your environment, then you might need to check `pip list` as well. Although, I think it should show up in `conda list`

Comment: @Jimmy why does it matter what the default Python for Ubuntu is?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Perhaps it doesn't but his error message contains references to python2.7 libraries while Anaconda 3 is using python 3.x.